# What is approve function doing in this code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

This code is snippet from a smart contract, In the code below:

1. ***who is approving whom and whose funds are cDai allowed to transfer within the given _amount?***
2. ***what is dai.approve doing?***
3. ***If contract is depositing funds to compound, why I should use approve cDai?***

   ```
    function _depositToCompound(uint256 _amount) internal returns (uint256) {
    require(dai.approve(address(cDai), _amount));

    uint256 result = cDai.mint(_amount);
    return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The approve function approves usage of the token to be transferred given the `_amount`.

1. The wallet that calls the function is approving the DAI contract to use `_amount` from the wallet.
2. `dai.approve` uses the `approve` function which takes in two parameters, `spender` and `amount`.
3. Your contract is using `cDai` to run a `mint` function, which I assume you're depositing `cDai`.

You can read more on approval [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-).